# CancellationTokensource with delay/timeout - differentiate afterwards what happened?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, async-await, cancellation

When initializing a [CancellationTokenSource with a delay value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139229%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set, is it possible to check afterwards what exactly happened - whether the timeout time was reached or whether .Cancel(..) was called explicitely?

Right now the OperationCanceledException that occurs after the delay *seems* to have no such indicator, but maybe I am missing it somehow.

Answer (score 3):

One way to work around that would be to have two separate `CancellationTokenSource`s: one for the delay and one for manual cancellation. You would then combine them into one using [`CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642265) and use that. When the combined token source is canceled, you can check the two original token sources to see what happened.